# How can I set a custom style for viewing images?

Tags: html

How can I do that? Because I don't really know the word but I hope somebody knows this.
If you guys don't understand this then there is a link.
https://media1.tenor.com/images/0f097ed319d498c2bda3d87ba4f6ff10/tenor.gif?itemid=12846096

It's a gif but they set it into a cool style and I don't know how to set it like that.

Comment: what's your question?  Set it like what? The image doesn't tell us anything

Answer (score 0):

The page most likely isn't actually a gif image, it could be some file structure like

```
> tenor.gif
>> index.html
```

where tenor.gif is actually a folder, with index.html inside it. Per W3C standard, folders automatically open up index.html if there is one directly inside it.
You could put whatever html code you want in index.html and styling.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the contrast of the styles in the CSS documentation, they usually add you to the styles and filters, so they are fully configurable